# How understand the result of incrementing and printing a global variable by two threads?

Tags: concurrency

In my main I have two threads running the following function:

```
int i = 0;    

void foo()
{
   ++i;
   printf("%d", i);
}
```

I ran it 10000 times and I had 3 different results:
{1 2}, {1 1}, {2 1}

First two I understand. The question is how the result can be {2 1} and why {2 2} doesn't appear at all.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a *data race*, since you access a non-atomic object from two different threads without locking.  Data races in C trigger undefined behavior and may result in any output whatsoever, or a crash, or anything else.  So in a certain sense, there is no point in understanding why the code has any particular behavior; what you should do instead is fix it to obtain the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that this is a race. My goal is not to have a correctly working code but to understand the reasons of certain results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why any particular instance of undefined behavior happens to execute in a particular way on a particular machine, you usually have to read the assembly code generated by the compiler.  [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/rK67vs) is what gcc 10.2 on x86-64 produces.  It does roughly the following:

1. Load `i` from memory into a register
2. Increment the register
3. Store the register back to `i`
4. Pass the contents of the register to `printf`.

So imagine that the threads happen to do those steps in the following order:

```
Thread A                  Thread B
--------                  --------
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
                          Step 1
                          Step 2
                          Step 3
                          Step 4
Step 4
```

Then you can clearly see that the output will be `2 1`.

As to why `2 2` never occurs, note that the value to be printed is loaded at step 1.  One of the two threads must execute step 1 before the other, or at the same time.  Thus at least one of them will load `0` at step 1, and therefore will print `1`.  Even if the other thread happens to have updated the value of `i` in memory before the first thread prints its value, it won't make any difference because the value to be printed is already in a register in the first thread.

(Of course it is entirely possible that some other compiler would generate code where `i` is reloaded from memory, and in that case `2 2` could occur.  It just doesn't happen to be the case for this particular generated code.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply!
I changed my code a little bit I made i volatile. Now the value of i which is passed to printf is gonna be updated so the result of the example you gave is going to be 2 2. 
But I still sometimes get 2 1. Could you please explain this case as well?

Comment: @Miriam: So, add a step 3.5 above where `i` is reloaded from memory back into a register (or onto the stack).  Then suppose thread B does all its work in between when A executes steps 3.5 and 4.  Remember that C is pass-by-value, so in order to pass `i` as a parameter to `printf`, a copy of it has to be made.  If thread B runs in between when that copy is made and when it's printed, you'll get `2 1`.